# I have this annoying scroll wheel icon next to my cursor

Tags: mouse-cursor

I have this annoying scroll wheel icon next to my cursor:

[image]

I hate this so much it stops me from scrolling but it goes away for a second when I return it back it appears again.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What brand of mouse are you using? This looks like a Microsoft mouse driver with advanced options enabled.

Comment: a4tech, the mouse doesnt have its own editor but my dad installed a screen capture tool (thats the actual name) but it was a mouse editor and since i opened it this has been here